# can anyone please tell me how to create a custom datePicker view in android. I have searched the whole google but could not find it.

Tags: android, android-widget

I want to learn how to create custom android views. I don't want to use any library. I have looked searched for it.

Comment: `I searched, but I didn't find`. **NO**, you didn't search at all. Otherwise, you would have found a godzillion results.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Check the Stack Overflow's [help on asking questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) first, please. Focus on [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask), [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create your own view using layouts and inject into the view by dialog. On click you can handle the calendar object.

Comment: Thank you for atleast taking it serious.